# jhipster@4.0 webpack visualstudio code with chrome debugger sourcemap not found

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, visual-studio-code, jhipster

I followed jhipster installation and was able to run latest jhipster. I want to debug angular2 code with visual studio code with chrome debugger installed and below run configuration

{

```
"version": "0.2.0",

"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost, with sourcemaps",
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "url": "http://localhost:9000",
        // This forces chrome to run a brand new instance, allowing existing
        // chrome windows to stay open.
        "userDataDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/chrome",
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
        //"diagnosticLogging": true,
        "sourceMapPathOverrides": { "webpack:///C:*":"C:/*" }
    }
]
```

}

and i see below errors and vs code would not hit debug break points

SourceMaps.loadSourceMapContents: Could not download sourcemap from http://localhost:9000/toSubscriber.js.map ...etc

jhipster uses webpack and it doesnot produce source maps. how to create these source maps?